# Check if ArgParse optional argument is set or not (in Julia)

Tags: julia, argparse.jl

This is essentially the same question as: [Check if argparse optional argument is set or not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30487767/855050), but in Julia, using [Julia's ArgParse module](https://github.com/carlobaldassi/ArgParse.jl).

Given an argument that takes a value, I want to know if its value was given or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, once you have parsed the arguments, you can check if an argument was set as `parsed_args["argname"] == nothing` (will return `true` if it was **not** set).

Find bellow a self-contained example (sightly modified [example1](https://github.com/carlobaldassi/ArgParse.jl/blob/master/examples/argparse_example1.jl) from `ArgParse.jl`) with 2 arguments that prints true if an argument was **not** set (just replace `==` with `!=` for the opposite behaviour):

```
using ArgParse

function main(args)

    # initialize the settings (the description is for the help screen)
    s = ArgParseSettings(description = "Example usage")

    @add_arg_table s begin
        "--opt1"               # an option (will take an argument)
        "arg1"                 # a positional argument
    end

    parsed_args = parse_args(s) # the result is a Dict{String,Any}

    println(parsed_args["arg1"] == nothing)
    println(parsed_args["opt1"] == nothing)
end

main(ARGS)
```

And example command line calls (assuming above is stored in `test.jl`):

```
>>> julia test.jl
true
true

>>> julia test.jl 5
false
true

>>> julia test.jl 5 --opt1=6
false
false

>>> julia test.jl --opt1=6
true
false
```

---

However, sometimes it might be more appropriate to define a default value for the parameter rather than checking if it was set. It can be done by adding the `default` keyword to the parameter:

```
@add_arg_table s begin
    "--opt1"
    "--opt2", "-o"
        arg_type = Int
        default = 0
    "arg1"
        required = true
end
```

aswell as the `required` keyword for the positional parameters, which would force the user to introduce it.

Comment: If an argument has a default value, can I know if it was passed?

Comment: @becko You can compare it to the default value... but if the user introduces exactly the default value I couldn't find a way of differenciating the two cases.