# how to get argparser arguments name?

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to parse arguments passed from command line.I am passing 15 arguments at all. I am trying to group those by giving them same destination () I need to group those. Now when I print input i get lists f.e [mylogo.png, otherlogo.png] and so on. How I could get a result similar to {destination:'value1','value2'} . I know I could do it manually but It's not a solution in my case..

```
   parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='Moodle automation', add_help= False,
                                     description=description(), usage='nana nanan nana')
   parser.add_argument('-logo', '--set_logo',
                        help='',
                        dest='branding',
                        type=str,
                        action='append')

    parser.add_argument('-c_logo', '--set_compact_logo',
                        help='',
                        dest='branding',
                        type=str,
                        action='append'
                        )


    web_status.add_argument('-wn', '--web_new',
                            help=" ",
                            dest='web_state',
                            action="append")

    web_status.add_argument('-wo', '--web_old',
                            help="",
                            dest="web_state",
                            action="append")
    args = parser.parse_args()
     branding_details = args.branding
     print(branding_details)
```

in case input:

```
program.py -logo mylogo.png -c_logo custom_logo.png
```

I get output  `['mylogo.png', 'custom_logo.png']`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30487767/check-if-argparse-optional-argument-is-set-or-not? Then check if `args.arg1 is not None and args.arg2 is not None`

Comment: With that setup you'll get two: `args.branding` and `args.web_state`.  With `append` you should get lists (if not the default `None`).

Comment: I think you missed the important part in question. Exactly which statements you are using   to parse and print the arguments provided over command line?

Comment: What's `web_status`?  You code bits leave too many ambiguitities.

Comment: @TejasSarade I editted my question. Copy paste issue..

Answer (score 1):

If you just `print(vars(args))`, it will give output like this. `vars()` is always a handy function if you are dealing with object names.

```
{'branding': ['mylogo.png', 'custom_logo.png']}
```

It is just matter of removing those square brackets [] from output and if you are using multiple destinations, you can iterate over the `args` dictionary to get desired output.

```
args_dict = vars(args)
for k, v in args_dict.items():
    print("{", k, ":", str(v).strip('[]'), "}")
```

output:

```
{ branding : 'mylogo.png', 'custom_logo.png' }
```

OR even better formatting with

```
args_dict = vars(args)
for k, v in args_dict.items():
    print('{{{0}: {1}}}'.format(k, str(v).strip('[]')))
```

output:

```
{branding: 'mylogo.png', 'custom_logo.png'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete minimal example, where we can give several `logo` and `compact_logo` with `nargs='*'`. The result contains lists of arguments.

`cli` represents an example string you would to pass to the program.

```py
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='Moodle automation', add_help= False,
                                 description='', usage='nana nanan nana')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--set_logo',
                    help='',
                    dest='logo',
                    nargs='*',
                    type=str)

parser.add_argument('-c', '--set_compact_logo',
                    help='',
                    dest='compact_logo',
                    nargs='*',
                    type=str)

cli = '-l mylogo.png -c custom_logo_1.png custom_logo_2.png'
args = parser.parse_args(cli.split())
print("List of arguments")
print(args.logo)
print(args.compact_logo)
print("Create a dict of key values for arguments")
dict_key_args = {key: value for key, value in args._get_kwargs()}   
# Create the following data structure
# {'compact_logo': ['custom_logo_1.png', 'custom_logo_2.png'],
# 'logo': ['mylogo.png']}
```