# Argparser interactive

Tags: argparse

My question is pretty straight,
Is argaparse has an option to prompt missed arguments just via input?

script.py:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('mode', metavar='', help='Set count of likes', default=49)
parser.add_argument('-n', '--number', metavar='', help='Set count of likes', default=49, required=True)
parser.add_argument('-f', '--frequency', metavar='', help='Set chance to like/dislike', default=70)
# Running it via bash:
$ python script.py
# argparse automaticaly checking that missed argument "--number" and asking it via input built-in
>>> (argparse) Missed required argument "number", please specify it now, number:
```

Comment: You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30488411/9997212), but inside the condition you insert an `input`.

Comment: No. Drop the `required`, and give it a reasonable default.  Or if absolutely necessary, use `input` after parsing.  But what's wrong with expecting the user to call the script again with all the required values?  That's what the error message with usage is for.